# How to get span data with lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to get the price change data from bloombergs website but i can't seem to get the info.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lx

bb = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/AAPL:US'

results = dict()

bb1 = requests.get(bb)
p1 = lx.fromstring(bb1.content)
p1xpath = p1.xpath('//span[contains(@id,"changeAbsolute")]')
for y, p1xpath in enumerate(p1xpath):
    span_id = p1xpath.xpath('.//@id')[0]
    span_text = [x.strip() for x in p1xpath.xpath('.//text()')]
    results[i] = dict(id=span_id, text = span_text)
    print (results)
```

Am a noob so a simple explanation will help a lot. Thanks

Comment: `xpath` returning empty list that's why you are not getting the results

Comment: I've tried multiple different methods, but can't seem to get anything other than an empty list.

Comment: are you sure the url you are using is right

Comment: what value are u looking for ? -1.83? a visual of ur expected output would help significantly

Comment: i think the data is rendered via javascript; an alternative would be to view the network details. Tinkering around and I found ur data in this link : https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/quote/EQT/AAPL%3AUS?locale=en. u should see ur price change there.

Comment: Yes. Looking for -1.83.I'll see if i can get it with that link. thanks

Comment: Hey Guys. So. I was actually looking at the wrong problem. Turns out, the requests response was their "are you a robot?". So I decided to scrape from yahoo finance instead and it works beautifully.

Thanks for all your help tho. The info helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So. I was actually looking at the wrong problem. Turns out, the requests response was their "are you a robot?". So I decided to scrape from yahoo finance instead and it works beautifully.

komatiraju032 and  sammywemmy answered the question. By asking if i was looking at the wrong data. Which i was.